# Save custom stencil with diagram in Visio so others can use the stencil and update the diagram

Tags: windows, microsoft-visio-2010

Say I have a Visio 2010 diagram foo.vsd and I've used a third-party stencil bar.vss in the diagram. Other team members will need to also open and edit foo.vsd. Is there a way to include the stencil in the diagram so that it's available to them when they open foo.vsd? (Similar to embedding fonts in a Word document.) If there is I haven't found it in some hours of research.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed stencils in the way you can with fonts in Word, all you can do is to add a reference to the stencil. However, shapes that are already included in the diagram are stored in the Document Stencil, so if you ensure every shape has been used at least once (even if it then gets deleted afterwards) there will be a copy in the Document Stencil. You can access this from More Shapes -> Document Stencil.